# Update dynamic slug on resolve ui-router

Tags: angularjs, url, routes, angular-ui-router

Because I have to build my urls SEO friendly and because I can't trust the user output. I want redefine this input when the resolve function returns me success.

Example :

The user writes : `http//mydomain.com/city/Newcastle upon Tyne` .

The API returns me the correct slug : `newcastle-upon-tyne-0191` and loads the template.

I want reverse the user inputs with this slug like this before the templates load :

`http//mydomain.com/city/newcastle-upon-tyne-0191`.

I'm using UI router, it is a way for do this ($state, $stateparams) ?

Here is the part of my router code which work with :

```
   .state('villes.ville', {
        url: "/:ville",
        cache: false,
        parent: 'villes',
        templateUrl: "partials/ville.tpl.html",
        metaTags: {
            title: '{{city.label}} ({{city.zip_code}})',
        },
        resolve: {
            city: function(City, $state, $stateParams){

                return City.get({
                    slug: $stateParams.ville,
                    shape: true,
                    details: true

                }).$promise.then(
                    function(data){ return data },
                    function(error){ $state.go('/404') });
            }
        },
        controller : 'villeCtrl'               
    })
```

Comment: once you have the data, can you not just call $state.go('villes.ville', {ville:'new data'})?

Comment: Oh, I had not even thought of ! I'm going to try.

Comment: Humm, I enter in infinite loop scope.go(). Makes sense

Comment: put a condition round the new state.go, so you only call it if the slug changes

Comment: It seems to : $location.url('/villes/'+ data.slug); works better (no loop) but the resolve function is called twice. I tried to wrapp the get() service into a if (typeof $state.params.ville == 'undefined') for filtering the first call but its not working. Have you an idea ?